# Webpack "Module not found" error when I try to import a TypeScript interface from a library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, font-awesome

I have a React project and I'm converting it to TypeScript as I go, so new components are TypeScript but old ones are JavaScript. Im also introducing FontAwesome via it's React component.

Everything works fine until I import an interface from `fontawesome-common-types` which causes a compilation error.

This works until I uncomment the first line:

```
// import { IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types';
import * as React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faAngleRight } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';

export type Props = {
  links: {
    text: string;
    icon: any; // This is what I need IconDefinition for
    url: string;
  }[];
};

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ links }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        links.map((link,index)=>(
          <li key={index}>
            <a href={link.url}>
              {link.text}
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={link.icon} />
            </a>
          </li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  );
};
```

At which point I get this error:

> ERROR in ./src/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.tsx
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types' in '/Users/MYNAME/projects/PROJECT/src/components/MyComponent'

In tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks":  true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types` exists ?

Comment: check package description: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome#typescript

Comment: Im not sure if I understand. I can see the IconDefinition is exported from: 
 node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types/index.d.ts

Comment: @demkovych changing the import to this and it works: import { IconDefinition } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'; Would be great to have an explanation why.